# Array to string avoiding first comma?

Tags: php

I am pushing `ids` to an `array` but there might be only one single `id` too, I then need to send this value to an input text:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="portfolioTitle" value="<?php echo implode(", ", $ids); ?>">
```

The problem is that if I only have 1 single `id`, I get this as `value`:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="portfolioTitle" value=", 128545">
```

How can I remove the comma if I only have a single value, like the following?

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="portfolioTitle" value="128545">
```

Though of doing a `foreach` for the `array` before to `echo` the values but I am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: If there's only a single value in the array you won't get a comma in the output of implode. You must be pushing a blank value into the array before you push any id values.

Comment: @Nick I should be doing `array_filter($ids)` isn't it?

Comment: tried this but I get `Array` echo $ids = array_filter($ids); implode(", ", $ids);

Comment: Can you var_dump $ids?

Comment: @NathanDawson `array(2) {
  [0]=>
  NULL
  [1]=>
  int(128545)
}`

Comment: The problem is with the way you're filling in `$ids` in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `implode()` on your array as you're doing now is the correct way to display it as a string. The output you're seeing suggests you might have an empty element in your array which is where filtering comes in.

```
<?php echo implode(', ', array_filter($ids)); ?>
```

`array_filter()` is going to remove any elements from your array that are equal to false. This will strip out your blank elements leaving you wish just the values you need.

Comment: It would probably be better to fix the code that creates `$ids` so it doesn't put nulls in.

Comment: ok thanks this works, but yes indeed I will now double check this is happening at all, I will accept it as soon a sit let me to.

Comment: @Barmar no arguments there :)

Comment: ok got the issue on the other end but I will leave this question open tho and accept your answer too, thanks Nathan.